# How do I select a created jQuery UI tab?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm working on a project where I need to create tabs and I need to activate the last created tab.

I'm using JUI 1.9 but I can't find documentation about it.

This is some code I use to create tabs:

```
 function addSearchResult(title, content) {
     var id = "tabs-" + tabId,
     li="<li><a href='#"+id+"'>"+title+"</a><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'></span></li>";

     tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
     tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "' data-index='"+indexTab+"'><p>" + content + "</p></div>" );
     indexTab++;


     tabs.tabs('option','active', indexTab); /*THIS IS NOT WORKING FOR ME :S */
     tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I haven't tried this - but looks like there is a bug in your code. Try changing to:

```
 function addSearchResult(title, content) {
 var id = "tabs-" + tabId,
 li="<li><a href='#"+id+"'>"+title+"</a><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'></span></li>";

 tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
 tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "' data-index='"+indexTab+"'><p>" + content + "</p></div>" );
 indexTab++;


 tabs.tabs('option','active', indexTab-1); /* NOTE THE -1  */
 tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
```

}

You have a post-increment on your indexTab variable, so need to take 1 off by the looks of it when you set the current tab.

Comment: It worked ! Thank you so much. I'd not realized tabs are 0 indexed

Answer (score 0):

You could fake a click

```
 tabs.find("li:last a").click()
```